# EvaluateScriptAsync hanging

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cefsharp

In CefSharp WinForms, I'm trying to get the html source of the page using JS once the page has loaded, however the application is freezing. I'm using a BackgroundWorker and the concerned functions are as follows:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    browser.Load("http://www.google.com");

    browser.FrameLoadEnd += delegate
    {
        object js = EvaluateScript(browser, "1+1");
        MessageBox.Show(js.ToString());
    };
}

object EvaluateScript(ChromiumWebBrowser b, string script)
{
    var task = b.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst you assign `FrameLoadEnd` in the `BackgroundWorker` thread, it's actually executed on the underlying `CEF UI` thread, for which you cannot block without issues.

I'd typically suggest you spawn a `Task` from within the event handler to complete your work.

Answer (score 6):

As amaitland pointed out, FrameLoadEnd was causing the hang by running in the UI thread. The below code is working:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    first.Load("http://www.google.com");

    browser.FrameLoadEnd += delegate
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => {
            object js = EvaluateScript(browser, "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;");
            MessageBox.Show(js.ToString());
        });
        task.Start();
    };
}

static object EvaluateScript(ChromiumWebBrowser b, string script)
{
    var task = b.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
    task.Wait();
    JavascriptResponse response = task.Result;
    return response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "") : response.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, it's a bad idea to use `Task.Wait` on async code; rather, you should [use async "all the way down"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). See also [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary. The short answer is that if you do this in an application with a synchronization context, you can cause a circular wait for the synchronization context (and hence a deadlock). The article I linked to has several examples of this, but I'd *strongly* suggest replacing `Task.Wait` with `await` here if possible.